# First Contentful Paint on localhost

Tags: core-web-vitals

I have a sample express.js app:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>`)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

If I run this on localhost and open lighthouse tab in developer tools and measure performance I am getting FCP of 0.7 seconds for mobile (0.2 seconds for desktop).

Why is there such delay on localhost? Shouldn't it be almost instant?

Comment: Network time is only one factor. What does the waterfall performance chart from developer tools in your browser show you?  See https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Tools/Performance/Waterfall for some information about how to create and interpret one.